# Read PDF and Extract page ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, ocr

We ask the our users to print of a multi page form, fill it in, scan it and upload it to our site.

I need to be able to programmaticly find one specific page from the uploaded pdf based on a pattern that I can add (such as a Cross or a barcode) and then split the pdf to pick up that one page.

A pdf text reader won't work because, the pdf is scanned in.

Any suggestions on how to go about it would be helpful.

Comment: You can try using Microsoft office document imaging. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_Document_Imaging, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/982760

Comment: Appreciate the input. But MODI won't work because, (1) It is our site's user that are scanning in the form and them uploading it. (2) MODI only works with TIFF & MDI formats whereas most files uploaded by our users are multipage PDF's.

Comment: you can use iTextSharp etc. to first convert pdf to png/tiff and then use MODI

Comment: @atur iTextSharp can not convert PDF to images.

Comment: @Bobrovsky : iTextSharp does convert pdf to images. Extract every page via iTextSharp using splitting and then convert/extract image for  each scanned page to `png` using library/functions provided in iTextSharp.

Comment: @atur iTextSharp can *not* create images from PDFs (can not render / rasterize PDFs). It can be used to extract existing images.

Comment: @Bobrovsky: My comments here does not answer to how to add image to scanned pdf but to suggest in `able to programmaticly find one specific page from the uploaded pdf based on a pattern`. i.e. get text from scanned pdf and and match it based on pattern. and I suppose that is what OP requires.

Comment: @atur you have named iTextSharp as a tool that can *convert pdf to png/tiff*. I made a note that this tool can't do that.

Comment: atur, Bobrovsky - in a way you both are right. iTextSharp cannot *render* a PDF page as an image, but it can *extract* images from it. In case of scanned PDF files that most often is preferable to rendering. That been said, the OP indeed should extract the page images (using iTextSharp or another PDF library) and analyze those images.

Comment: Thanks for all the input guys. Do we have ideas, on how to search the image for a pattern. Such as a Cross on the top right of the page? MODI seems to support OCR, which would not pick up patterns. Unless I am missing something.